# Convert simple PostGIS polygon layer to polygon topogeometry

Tags: postgis, postgresql, topology

I have created a topology schema 'parcele_topo' with the default tables edge_data, face, node and relation. I also imported a polygon shapefile to this schema using shp2pgsql-gui as table 'parcele_tsur_116'. I added a topogeometry column (named 'topo') to this table using:

```
select topology.addtopogeometrycolumn('parcele_topo','parcele_topo','parcele_tsur_116','topo','polygon');
```

This is the topology summary:

```
Topology parcele_topo (id 3, SRID 2462, precision 0.005)0 nodes, 0 edges, 0 faces, 0 topogeoms in 0 layers Layer 1, type Polygonal (3), 0 topogeoms Deploy: parcele_topo.parcele_tsur_116.topo
```

And this is the screenshot:

[image]

Now I want to convert this simple table to topogeometry layer inside this topology schema so I can use topological analyses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- Create topology schema

```
select topology.createtopology('schema',srid,tolerance);
```

2-Create table structure identical the one that will be converted

```
create table schema.table2 
(like schema.table1 including all);
```

3-Add topogeometry column to the table

```
select topology.addtopogeometrycolumn('schema','yourtopology','table2','topo','polygon');
```

4-Check the topology info

```
select topology_id,layer_id,schema_name as sn,feature_column as fc
from topology.layer;

select * from topology.topologysummary('yourtopology');
```

5-If everything is set up, proceed to the insertion of the data

```
insert into schema.table2(attribute1,topo)
select attribute1,topology.totopogeom(geom,'yourtopology',1)
from schema.table1;
```

Reference material:

https://postgis.net/docs/toTopoGeom.html